# Finding 2 people with maximum number of connections in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1 table

user_id
connection_id

sample data

```
u_id, c_u_id  
12345, 23456 |
12345, 34567 |
23456, 34567 |
56789, 23456 |
56789, 34567 |
```

A user can have multiple records for each connection he has.

How can i write a sql to find the 2 people that have the maximum mutual connections?

Comment: "he 2 connections that have the most common connections" ?  I don't understand.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: how many connections is allowed between 2 specific users!? more than one!!!??

Comment: user ids are unique so 2 specific users can be connected in only one way. Think of it as a facebook connection

Comment: so `for 2 specific user (let say u1 and u2) we can have maximum 2 connections which are:  u1,u2 and u2,u1`, so what do you mean by: _2 people with maximum number of connections in sql_ ?

Comment: do you mean `top 2 users with highest number of connections?`

Comment: What I mean is which 2 users have the maximum mutual connections?

Comment: I mean is top 2 users with highest number of mutual connections

Comment: Ok, so just answer this question: if we have `u1,u2` then should we have also `u2,u1` in the table or not?

Comment: yes, if you have u1, u2 then you will also have u2, u1 in the table.

Comment: but your sample data haven't matched your conditions, edit it and provide a fully matched sample data with desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a self join for this.  Assuming your table has no duplicates:

```
select t1.u_id, t2.u_id, count(*)
from table t1 join
     table t2
     on t1.c_u_id = t2.c_u_id and
        t1.u_id < t2.u_id
group by t1.u_id, t2.u_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

If you can have duplicate rows, replace the `count(*)` with `count(distinct t1.c_u_id)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works perfectly. Only thing to add is that Order By clause on count(*) desc so to pick the 2 userids with maximum mutual connections